# I want to extract the file name and slice it to take a part and put this part in a column of the excel. And i want to do this for 8 files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I am trying to extract a part of the excel file name and add it to the new column in the same excel. I want to do this for 8 files.

I could slice a part of the file name but I am unable to add it in its column.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

output = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):

    x = file
    slice1, slice2 = 13, 17
    final = [x[slice1:slice2]]
    x['Out'] = final
    output.to_excel("outPut.xlsx", index = False, na_rep = "NA", header=True)
```

For Ex :

I have 8 excels with file name "ABC_Alphwise_OUT1" , "ABC_Alphwise_OUT2" and so on. I want to slice the file name first to get "OUT1", "OUT2" and so on.

Then I want "OUT1", "OUT2" and so on to be added in a column of the excels "ABC_Alphwise_OUT1" , "ABC_Alphwise_OUT2" and so on respectively.

I have given 2 input and output for sample.

Inputs:

[ABC_Alphwise_OUT1 : 1st Excel input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgJpe.png)

[ABC_Alphwise_OUT2 : 2nd Excel input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwvB4.png)

Outputs

[ABC_Alphwise_OUT1 : 1st Excel Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Unr.png)

[ABC_Alphwise_OUT1 : 2nd Excel Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A59Vi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it now, each excel file has x number of rows. You want to append a column to that excel file with that extracted and transformed name (`file_slice`) of the file repeated x number of times.

First, let's get the `file_slice` and load the excel file as a `pandas` dataframe. Then we get the number of rows in the excel sheet (`len(df.index)`), and create a list of the `file_slice` duplicated the same number of times. The list is then appended to the dataframe in a new column `Out`. The dataframe can then overwrite the original excel file.

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd

for file in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    file_slice = file[slice1:slice2]
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    file_slice_list = [file_slice]*len(df.index)
    df['Out'] = pd.Series(file_slice_list).values
    df.to_excel(file, index=False, na_rep = 'NA', header = True)
```

Comment: I want the column to be added in its original excel sheet and not the in new excel.

Comment: @NidhiBakshi, does the original excel already have an `Out` column and you want to append to it, or do you want to create a new column? It would be helpful if you can show the original excel sheet you want to change.

Comment: Original excel doesn't have the "OUT" column. I want to append to the this column to the existing excel. I am editing my question to add the example of excel.

Comment: I want just that particular file's name in that particular file, but appended to all rows in that file